# Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation in karaf

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, apache-karaf

**How to overcome this chain dependency issue.?**

```
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
        Error starting bundle 429: Could not resolve module: com.sample.eventhistory [429]
  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource com.sample.eventhistory [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.sample.eventhistory"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.90.0.SNAPSHOT"] because it exports package 'com.sample.restenquiry.exceptions' and is also exposed to it from resource com.sample.eventhistory [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.sample.eventhistory"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.90.0.SNAPSHOT"] via the following dependency chain:

 

  com.sample.eventhistory [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.sample.eventhistory"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.90.0.SNAPSHOT"]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=com.sample.restutil.impl)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.sample.restutil.impl; uses:=com.sample.restservice
  rest [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="edmexporest"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.90.0.SNAPSHOT"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sample.restservice)(&(version>=1.90.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: com.sample.restservice; uses:=com.sample.restenquiry.exceptions
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.sample.restenquiry.exceptions
  com.sample.eventhistory [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.sample.eventhistory"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.90.0.SNAPSHOT"]
```

while deploying the bundle services is not comming up . Instead getting the above error in karaf console

Answer (score 0):

OSGi allows the same packages to be exported-- AS LONG as the version numbers are different. In this case, you have the same package+version being exported by two bundles.

A good practice is to put the interfaces and exceptions in one bundle (ie service-api), then the consumer bundle and the provider bundle can both import those packages, but not require you to have the consumer depend directly on the provider.

Comment: as this issue I am getting while migrating for Apache felix to DS implementation[osgi]. I am using maven-bundle-plugin version 3.2.0 in my pom.xml @MattPavlovich